# How to remove an array from an object using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My objective is to remove an array[] from an object. I couldn't able to figure out how to remove the particular array from the object. Can anyone help me with this query?

Here is the following object:

```js
experience: [
    {
        organisation: "",
        id: "",
        from: "",
        to: "",
        skills: []
    }
]
```

`Experience` array having an object, it may have multiple objects.

```
experience: [
    {
        organisation: "",
        id: "",
        from: "",
        to: "",
        skills: []
    },
    {
        organisationName: "",
        id: "",
        from: "",
        to: "",
        skills: []
    }
]
```

I want to remove the `skills` array from every object.

I have tried in this way but it is showing undefined.

```
 let skillsArray = this.state.experiences.forEach((item) => item.skills! == Array.isArray([]))
```

Can anyone please help me with this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you are trying to do, you need to use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method.
This method goes through each element of the array and returns with a new array where each element is what your function returns.

[forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) will go through all the items in your array and execute what you pass as a function for each element. In your code you are just doing a comparison which doesn't affects anything really.

To answer your question:

```js
let skillsArray = this.state.experiences.map((item) => {
  delete item.skills;
  return item;
})
```

But notice that in this example I'm also modifying the original array, so it might be better to *copy* each item and modify that instead.

```js
let skillsArray = this.state.experiences.map((item) => {
  let newItem = { ...item }
  delete newItem.skills;
  return newItem;
})
```

One more thing, this question is really about Javascript. React is not actually involved in any of this.

Comment: HI, Actually i want to remove the  skills item when i submit the form. When i use the above answer for submitting form then it is showing error like skills are undefined `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. It is removing everywhere i think

Comment: I guess you are using the first version of my answer. On the second one I'm copying the object so it doesn't modify the original.

Comment: But we're not assigning newItem anywhere

Comment: Hi, how to delete multiple properties from object? if i give `delete newItem.skills; delete newItem.to` then i'm getting in this way "The operand of a 'delete' operator must be optional."

Answer (score 1):

Map the `experience` array, destructure the `skills` property, and use rest syntax to collect the rest of the properties in an object, and return it:

```js
const state = {
  experience: [{
    organisation: "",
    id: "",
    from: "",
    to: "",
    skills: []
  }]
};

const newState = {
  ...state,
  experience: state.experience.map(
    ({ skills, ...rest }) => rest
  )
};
console.log(newState);
```

Comment: Hi, It is giving every variable available in state. but not removing skills from experience array

Comment: It is indeed removing the `skills` property from every object in the array - run the snippet to see for yourself. Are you sure you copied the code properly?

Comment: Yes, i copied the code, i'm using class component. In Submit method, when i use the above one, it is showing every state variable in the console

Comment: Because that's what the code is doing basically at the last line. On this answer `newState` is your `skillsArray` and `state` is your `this.state`

Comment: @tehsis - I have done that but still getting the same output

Comment: @Arunya Did you forget to assign the new state? It really sounds like it - press "Run code snippet" to see my code in action, it really does remove the `skills` property as you're expecting

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your list by the issue you want, and it will be auto removed, for example, if you want to remove all items = 3 :

```
list: prevState.list.filter(x=> x != 3);
```

Good luck!